# Streamlit integration and limitations

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, streamlit

I am new to streamlit and I have been asked to do a feasibility study for dashboarding solution. I want the help of you all to find out the answers of the below questions. I tried but was not able to get a clarity on these.

1. Is there any data limit that can be displayed for the streamlit library?
2. How long it would take to load data of varied sizes is there any way to find it or is load test the way to go?
3. How can I integrate streamlit with AWS S3, Athena and Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

1. yes 50k MB of uploaded data is the limit
2. not that long, and you can cache it so it doesn't reload.
3. integrations isn't problematic at all from my experience with AWS

You should explore a bit yourself, thats the best solution imo. Also, use streamlit community blog, it is much more active on those questions than stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out!